# String::erase throws length_error when using it with iterator

Tags: c++, string, iterator

```
stringstream str(line, ios_base::in);
while(!str.eof()){
    string word;
    str >> word;
    std::transform(word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), ::tolower);
    char c = *(--word.end());
    char b = *word.begin();
    if((c == ')' && b == '(') || (c == '\'' && b == '\'')){
        word.erase(--word.end());
        word.erase(word.begin()); //exception occurs here
    }
    c = *(--word.end());
    if(c == ',' || c == '.' || c == '?' || c == '!')
        word.erase(--word.end());
}
```

This code throws an std::length_error (what(): basic_string::_S_create) at word.erase(word.begin()); however if I change it to word.erase(0, 1); it works perfectly fine.

Why is that?

I am using gcc 4.8.1 (MinGW build)

Comment: Instead of `*(--word.end())` and `*word.begin()`, you  could use `word.back()` and `word.front()`.

Comment: What's the input to reproduce it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `line` consists of a single character

```
'
```

then

- the condition `(c == '\'' && b == '\'')` will pass, so we'll start to delete the beginning and end characters,
- `word.erase(--word.end());` will remove the only character, making the string empty,
- and then `word.erase(word.begin());` will crash, because `word.begin()` now doesn't point to a valid character in the string.  (I think it actually causes undefined behavior)

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple things wrong with your code:

1. You should **always** check that extraction from a stream was successful **after** trying to read fro the stream.
2. Using `std::istream::eof()` to terminate a loop does not work. You might want to use `eof()` to decide whether you want to report an error.
3. Using `std::tolower()` with `char`s on a platform where `char` is signed result in undefined behavior, e.g., for most encodings it will result in undefined behavior when using it with my last name.
4. When the `word` is empty all kinds of strange things can happen. Since you didn't check if you could successfully read a word, I guess this is what happens: `erase()` the position `begin()` points to when using it on a empty string will fail.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am aware of the first 3 points, but since it is a small program, which I will only use once and the input is limited to 1 encoding, I tend to leave these things out. The fourth one I forget about so thank you.